# Can’t set cookie from apigateway/lambda with cors

Tags: reactjs, cookies, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, api-gateway

im setting a cookie with set cookie from apigateway/lambda to react app in another domain with all the relevant heders:

```
“set-cookie”: “test=tests;samesite=none;secure=false;”,
“Access-Control-Allow-Headers” : “set-cookie, cookie; samesite=none;secure”,
“Access-Control-Allow-Origin”: “http://somedomain.com”,
“Access-Control-Allow-Methods”: “OPTIONS,POST,GET”,
“Content-Type”: “application/json”,
“Access-Control-Allow-Credentials”: “true”,
```

and i can see the set-cookie header in response but the cookie is not getting set in chrome.

can someone help with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant see cors cookies in dev-tools application tab:
[image: dev-tools application tab]

but you can see them in the network cookie tab:
[image: network cookie tab]